# Loading image pixels into 2D array

Tags: arrays, pixel

How do you load pixels of an image into a 2D array in C or C++?

Comment: Load them from where? An image file of some kind?

Comment: yes, an image file like .bmp etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DevIL (openil)](http://openil.sourceforge.net/tuts/tut_5/index.htm) to load an image file into an ILubyte array:

```
ILubyte *Lump;
ILuint Size;
FILE *File;

File = fopen("monkey.tga", "rb");
fseek(File, 0, SEEK_END);
Size = ftell(File);

Lump = (ILubyte*)malloc(Size);
fseek(File, 0, SEEK_SET);
fread(Lump, 1, Size, File);
fclose(File);

ilLoadL(IL_TGA, Lump, Size);
free(Lump);
```

First byte is red, second byte is green, third byte is blue, and so on. If you want a 2d array, it might be a good idea to write nested loops.

Comment: thanks! but what is ILubyte? Is it an inbuilt structure in C?

Comment: It is from openil (or devIL), probably a typedef of unsigned char